# Response time between Elasticsearch and Apache on Google Cloud lagspikes

Tags: elasticsearch, networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an Elasticsearch server with data in it and a Compute engine with a LAMP stack running on it.

Both servers:

1. **Elastic**. europe-west1-d - Compute Engine / 6 vCPU's, 34 GB Mem
2. **Lamp**. europe-west4-c - Compute Engine / 4 vCPU's, 23 GB Mem

Both servers never reach anywhere near 20% of their resource limits and they are super fast most of the time.

But sometimes, for a few minutes the connection between the two slows down to 42 second requests.

- The website shows in 200 ms, but the products that come from Elastic search using an AJAX requests keeps loading for 42 seconds
- If I go to Kibana the same query, or different queries take 35ms

So I cant find anything wrong on any of the servers resource wise, but could it be a Firewall problem, or maybe a DNS / datacenter thing. Does any1 have any clue as to what could be causing this? Feel free to pitch even the most farfetched ideas.

Comment: I don't think this could be caused by any firewall. Firewall won't slow down the connection, will make it either work or not work.You can do MTR to see where the high latency is taking place in the traffic path. For more troubleshooting, you can also do iperf test to measure latency and the effective packet throughput between VMs.